# How to add title bar background image programatically in android

Tags: android

I am new in android , How can add title bar background image programattically without change parent theme . My application is based on tab host . There are two tabs. I want to remove appname and app icon from title bar and want to add background image. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can infalte your custom layout to your title bar like this:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.your_custom_layout);
```

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.your_custom_layout); it gives error: Referenced part does not exist yet: org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView

Comment: are u sure u're passing existed layout instead of this R.layout.your_custom_layout ?

Comment: Thanks for help, I have solved my issue using this code: Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.top_header);  getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);